# VBA renaming files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with a large number of files. I have listed them all in a column OldName in a spreadsheet. I want to rename them to the name in column NewName in the same spreadsheet. I would like code that will look at the files in a folder (a mix of csv and xlsx) and use the OldName list to change the file name to NewName

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Checkout the [Name statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement) and give it a try. If you get stuck or errors come back with your code and a question to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+rename+file gives > 600 hits. Have you checked any of them?